# How to make first section name appear in header in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, context

For some reason, when I have several sections on one page, ConTeXt chooses second of them to appear in header:

```
\setupheadertexts[{header: \getmarking[section]}][]
\starttext
\startsection[title={123}]
abc
\stopsection
\startsection[title={456}]
def
\stopsection
\startsection[title={789}]
ghi
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

[image: this is what i get]

Is it possible to control what goes in header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\getmarking [section] [top]
```

and have a look at the [wiki page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/getmarking) explaining the different options.

Comment: Thank you! How stupid of me. But default behaviour looks strange anyway